# "There's not much point" vs. "There're not many points"

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

This is a primitive question, but I can't decide which one sounds more natural between them. Normally we can count *points*, but I'm not sure if the *point* in this expression is something we can count.

Answer (score 1):

In this case only the singular **point** makes sense.  The meaning of *point* here is

> [3: an end or object to be achieved : PURPOSE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/point)

so the idiom is saying that there is not much *purpose* to something, or not much reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

"Point" has various meanings and uses, and I think you may be confusing them.

When we say "there's no point" to something, we mean there is *no reason* for doing it - nothing to be gained, no purpose, no meaning. Although some of these synonyms (meaning, reason, purpose etc) can be countable, more often than not they are used singularly as if non-countable. You *could* say, for example, "*there are no reasons for doing it*" but that could suggest that you expect multiple reasons in order to do it rather than just one.

"Points" used in the plural usually refers to individualised facets of something, which could be sub-points of the main purpose. It doesn't mean the same in this context.

Answer (score 0):

"There's not much point" sounds more natural to me.

As others have noted, point here means purpose, so the singular form makes sense.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).